# Having trouble solving this separable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I am having some trouble with the following separable differential equation

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x(x-1)(x-3)$$

with initial condition $x(0) = 2$. What is $\displaystyle\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t)$?

I am having some trouble with the logarithmic laws when solving for $x(t)$.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to solve the differential equation $$ \frac{dx}{dt} = x(x-1)(x-3)$$ to answer the question.

Note that you have three equilibrium points, namely $$ x=0,1,3 $$

Qualitative analysis of these equilibrium points show that $x=1$ is asymptotically stable.

Thus starting at $x(0)=2$ the solution will tend to $x=1.$

Comment: Thanks! could you explain how I can see that x=1 is asymptotically stable?

Comment: When $1<x<3$, the derivative $\frac {dx}{dt}$ is  negative so the solution curve decreases and tends to x=1. For example at x=2 the derivative is $2(2-1)(2-3)=-2$ so the solution is decreasing.

Comment: I see that the derivative is negative, but why does the curve tend towards x=1 and not x=0 for example?

Comment: The  solutions can not cross each other because of the uniqueness.  Since x=1 is a solution by itself,  the other solution can not pass it to go to x=0.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer from Mohammad Riazi-Kermani : $x(t\to\infty)\to 1$.

The solving of the ODE leads to the same result :
$$t=\int\frac{dx}{x(x-1)(x-3)}=\int \left(\frac{1}{3x}-\frac{1}{2(x-1)}+\frac{1}{6(x-3)} \right)dx$$
$$6t=2\ln|x|-3\ln|x-1|+\ln|x-3|+\text{constant}$$

$$e^{-6t}=c\frac {(x-1)^3}{x^2(x-3)}$$
The condition $x(0)=2$ or $t(2)=0$ implies

$e^{0}=c \frac{2^2(2-3)}{(2-1)^3} \implies c=-4$ .
$$e^{-6t}=-4\frac{(x-1)^3}{x^2(x-3)} $$
For $t\to\infty\quad:\quad e^{-6t}\to 0.\quad$ Thus $x\to 1.$

Comment: OK. As you like. But it is simpler that way which avoids to check the sign of $c$ successively in the intervals $1<x<3$ and $x>3$. If you write $(x-3)$ instead of $|x-3|$ then $c=-4$ for $1<x<3$ .

Comment: OK. This is not essential. I will edit my answer to please you.

Comment: The same $c$ can not be at the same time $+4$ and $-4$. While it is not essential to the concluding argument, it is essential to the consistency of the steps before. // You could also directly have argued about the limits from the logarithm formula. $+∞$ on the left is only possible on the right for bounded $x$ if $x\to 1$, $\ln|x-1|\to-∞$.